# Considering a non-standard set theory

Tags: alternative-set-theories

I'm thinking of creating a non-standard set theory with urelements that has a certain restriction on a specific kind of sets which ZF set theory does not have. Informally, I would like for all set elements to be "equally nested" e.g. $\{a, b\}$ and $\{\{a\}, \{b\}\}$ would both be valid sets in this set theory, but $\{a, \{b\}\}$ would not.

How would one formalize this?

Comment: Do you want it by the axioms upward or ZF downward: Do you want to build axioms where this makes sense or do you want to take ZF and somehow impose this on that?In the second way you could maybe rig up all the operations and axioms to insist then when you are dealing with a set that is a finite nesting of sets of the same depth, then it is really the set containing those two sets without the nesting?

Comment: Are you familiar with Russel's typed set theory?

Comment: I would like to build axioms where this make makes sense. "In the second way you could maybe rig up all the operations and axioms to insist then when you are dealing with a set that is a finite nesting of sets of the same depth, then it is really the set containing those two sets without the nesting?" I don't want this! I want {a, b} and {{a},{b}} to be two different sets.

Comment: You will have to violate the Axiom of Pairing.

Comment: Why? ${} {} {} $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the set theory I have in mind should have a restricted version of the axiom of pairing. That is, only some, but not all, elements can be paired.

Comment: Apart from the axiom of pairing you have to reformulate the axiom schema of replacement and axiom of infinity. If you restrict these not to allow for non equi-nested sets you shouldn't be able to construct these. If these are constructed to be an consequence of the counterpart in standard set theory you should end up with a consistent theory (given that the standard is consistent). If you add an axiom that states that every set is equi-nested you might introduce a contradiction (but I don't believe so).

Comment: Uhh, unless $a=\{a\}$ and $b=\{b\}$ (or vice versa), the sets $\{a,b\}$ and $\{\{a\},\{b\}\}$ are ***entirely*** different. Also, if you are only allowed to have sets with elements of "the same rank", how do you plan on having an infinite set?

Comment: @skyking but how do I formulate "every set is equi-nested" in predicate logic? That is my real question. Given how Kuratowski finiteness is rather non-trivial, I expect the answer to this question to also be non-trivial.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila the elements of the countable infinite set will be urelements.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich As you're bound to have infinite number of urelements maybe you could make them or at least some of them fulfil the axioms of Peanno and hence be numbers. That way you could define a nesting number for each set (which is one more than the nesting number for it's members which all have the same)?

Comment: Also the axiom of extensionality may need to be reformulated in the precense of urelements. If $x\in u$ is allowed when $u$ is an ur-element then extensionality does not hold since $\neg x\in u$ for all ur-elements which would mean they all have the same (none) elements, but are considered different anyway.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich Another way to express nestedness is by use of schemas. For any given natural $n$ you can construct a formula that says that the nesting level of $X$ is $n$. The schema in naturalish language would be "whenever $a, b\in X$ then $n$ being the nesting level of $a$ is equivalent to $n$ being the nesting level of $b$".

Comment: Do you want also to impose the nesting requirement on sets not involving the urelements? For example, what about $\{\ \{\},\ \{\{\}\}\ \}$ or $\{\ a,\ \{\}\ \}$?

Comment: Consider looking into structural set theory -- e.g. ETCS, or maybe variations on type theory. These may already meet your needs.

Comment: @JDH good question, and yes I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In what follows, I'll try to set up the beginnings of a set theory matching your intuitions.**

First let's get the easy axioms down. Clearly we want extensionality - two sets are identical iff they have the same elements - except modified to allow urelements. There are multiple ways to do this, but I think the cleanest is to work in a two-sorted language, with one sort being for *sets* and the other for *urelements*; and have our language contain, besides the sort symbols, only the relation "$\in$." Then we have the axioms "If $x\in y$, then $y$ is a set," and "Two sets are the same iff they have the same elements;" let's call these two axioms together **Extensionality**.

The interesting bit, of course, is capturing the same-level restriction. I think the easiest way to formalize "every set is equi-nested" is the following:

- Say that $x$ is a *depth-$0$* element of $a$ if $x= a$. *This is a bit of an abuse of terminology, but it's useful below*.
- Say that $x$ is a *depth-$(n+1)$* element of $a$ if $x\in y$ for some depth-$n$ element of $a$.

*It will be useful to write "$x\in_n y$" for "$x$ is a depth-$n$ element of $y$;" note that for each $n$, this is an abbreviation of a formula in the usual language of set theory with set and urelement sorts, so we're not adding to the language by using these symbols.*

Then for each distinct $m, n\in\mathbb{N}$, we let $\psi_{m, n}$ be the sentence

> For all sets $x$ and $y$, we have $x\in_m y\implies x\not\in_ny$.

(Note that by contrapositive, $\varphi_{m, n}\equiv\varphi_{n, m}$.) These are the **Leveling** axioms.

The conjunction of the sentences $\varphi_{m, n}$ prevents the kind of "level-breaking" behavior you want to avoid - *without* having to explicitly give sets types. For example, the sentence $\psi_{0, 1}$ prevents $a=\{a\}$ (and prevents $a\in a$ in general). And sets like $\{a, \{a, b\}\}$ are ruled out by $\psi_{1,2}$.

Alright, now we have a "first approximation" of the set theory we want: let $T_0$ consist of extensionality + all the leveling axioms.

---

Let's think a little about how the set theory we're building goes from here.

One natural thing we want at this point is the concept of "same level" - even though we've deliberately avoided giving sets explicit levels, we still want to be able to talk about the sets of the same level as a given one. There are two natural ways to do this.

- We can look *up one level*: we write $a\sim_\uparrow b$ ("$a$ and $b$ have the same level from above") if there is some $x$ with $a, b\in x$.
- We can look *down one level*: we write $a\sim_{\downarrow } b$ ("$a$ and $b$ have the same level from below") if for all $x\in a$ and $y\in b$ there is some $c$ with $x, y\in c$.

*We can define other notions of "same level," by looking further above or below, but there doesn't seem to be a good reason to do so at the moment.*

These each suggest a corresponding **comprehension scheme**: for each formula $\varphi(x; \overline{y})$, we have the axioms $$(*)_\varphi^\uparrow\quad\forall a, \overline{b}\exists c\forall d(d\in c\iff \varphi(d, \overline{b})\wedge a\sim_\uparrow d)],$$ and $$(*)_\varphi^\downarrow \quad\forall a, \overline{b}\exists c\forall d(d\in c\iff \varphi(d, \overline{b})\wedge a\sim_\downarrow d)].$$

Each scheme is to be interpreted the same way: as saying that we can form the set of all things *of a given level* satisfying any first-order property. The difference is in how they interpret "level." Specifically, the point of separation is *urelements*.

We have a choice to make: *how do we want to treat urelements?* Specifically, do we want all urelements to have the same "level," or do we want to allow urelements to have different "levels?" The point is that if $u, v$ are urelements, then we trivially have $u\sim_\downarrow v$ (since neither has any elements at all) but we may not have $u\sim_\uparrow v$.

Thinking about this, we are led to two natural theories:

- If we want all urelements to be the same level, then it's natural in fact to demand that $\forall a, b(a\sim_\uparrow b\iff a\sim\downarrow b)$. Taking this, the theory $T_0$, and both (or equivalently, either) comprehension schemes gives us the theory $T_{flat}$.
- If we want to allow urelements to be on different levels, then we clearly don't want to allow the $(*)^\downarrow$-scheme, since they would let us form the set of all urelements. So for this purpose, we want the theory $T_0$ and just the $(*)^\uparrow$-scheme; the resulting theory is $T_{bumpy}$.

**From now on we'll write "$\sim$" for "$\sim_\uparrow$," the point being that in $T_{flat}$ they're equal and in $T_{bumpy}$ we're not directly interested in $\sim_\downarrow$.**

Clearly $T_{flat}$ implies $T_{bumpy}$. I suspect, though, that $T_{bumpy}$ will ultimately be the "right" one to look at.

---

Now let's take stock and see what we have so far!

What can we prove? One easy theorem of $T_\uparrow$ (and hence of $T_\downarrow$ as well) is that there is no "top level": for each $a$ there is a $b$ with $a\in b$; in fact, the set $\{a\}$ itself exists. We apply Leveling to the formula "$x=a$": then $a$ is the only thing with the same level as $a$ which is equal to $a$, so this gives us $\{a\}$.

Another easy result in both theories is that $\sim$ is preserved by set formation: if $a,b$ are sets, where every element of $a$ is $\sim$ every element of $b$ (equivalently, we can replace "every" with "some"), then $a\sim b$, and $\{a, b\}$ exists. This lets us construct [Kuratowski ordered pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition): if $a\sim b$ then the set $\{\{a\}, \{a, b\}\}$ exists.

That said, we can't prove **much**: the structure consisting only of $\{\}, \{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\}\}\}, ...$ is a model of both $T_\uparrow$ and $T_\downarrow$, so these are extremely weak axiom systems if we don't incorporate urelements. In fact, the only variety we'll be able to get in the "pure" (= urelement-free) part is by using *illfounded sets*! So this is a theory which works best in the additional presence of an [antifoundation axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory) appropriately formulated to play well with the leveling axioms. And as things stand, the situation doesn't change too much when we bring in urelements.

So the next thing to do is think about adding "stuff" to our theory. There are three general kinds of "stuff" that occur to me:

- Although the well-founded pure part of any model of these theories is basically trivial, **additional axioms** could make things much more interesting on the illfounded pure (and impure) part! For instance, one natural option is a version of powerset: that given a set $a$, the set of *nonempty* subsets of $a$ is again a set (we need nonempty because the emptyset has "level zero").
- We could **give the urelements structure** by expanding the language to include function and relation symbols on the urelements. So, e.g., we could have the set of urelements form a group. This idea of "building a set theory on top of a structure" is a common one in set theory with urelement, especially in higher computability theory where we often look at [a particular family of sets built "on top of" a given structure](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1974.1/Main/icm1974.1.0229.0234.ocr.pdf).
- The power of sets in ZFC comes from their versatility, and this versatility can be lost when we force strict type agreement as we've done here. So it's reasonable to drop the ZFC-intuition that "sets are enough," and **add some new sorts**! For instance, maybe we want to consider sequences of objects of possibly different "levels." In this case, we're viewing a sequence as a different kind of "thing" than a set. From a ZFC standpoint that feels weird, but here things are different - so maybe this is something we want to do!

So there are lots of directions we can go. But I'll stop here for now: even though we certainly don't have a satisfactory set theory yet, we have a decent start towards building in that direction.

Comment: I would be more inclined to design towards each level having an empty set, rather than just level zero. (I don't care whether it's the same empty set in each level, or each level gets its own distinct empty set)

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be to introduce the binary relation symbol $\prec$ (meaning having nesting level less than or equal). Then you add axioms that nail the meaning of this:

$$\forall A\forall B:(A\prec B) \leftrightarrow (\forall \xi: \xi\notin A \land \xi\notin B) \lor (\exists\beta\in B\forall\alpha\in A:\alpha\prec\beta)$$

That is the nesting level of $A$ is no larger than that of $B$ if the most nested element of $A$ is has no larger nesting level than the least nested element of $B$.

Then we can formulate the equi-nested requirement:

$$\forall A \forall \xi,\eta\in A:\xi\prec \eta \land \eta\prec\xi$$

Also we need to adapt the axiom of extensionality to cope with ur-elements:

$$\forall A\forall B: (\forall \xi: \xi\in A\leftrightarrow \xi\in B) \leftrightarrow A=B \lor (\forall\xi: \xi\notin A\land\xi\notin B)$$

Apart from this we need to reformulate some of the normal axioms to prevent formation of non-equinested sets. We need to reformulate the axiom of pairing, schema of replacement to prohibit this. Also we need to do something about the axiom of infinity since the normal aproach is to construct the infinite set using differently nested sets.

One approach borrowing from Peanno's axioms would be to postulate a non-empty set of ur-elements with a injection to a proper subset of itself.

(*) I use here the construct that allow membership relation on ur-elements, that is an ur-element is an element $U$ such that $\forall x:x\notin U$